# Defining weekday and weekend in WEKA dataset?

Tags: weka

this is a small part of my dataset:

```
@relation
@attribute ID {'1','2','3','4','5'}
@attribute is_Weekend {Saturday, Sunday}
@attribute Weekday {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}
@attribute Leaving_Time {'07:00<=x<09:00','09:00<=x<12:30'}

@data
'1',??,,'09:00<=x<12:30'
'2',??,'09:00<=x<12:30'
'3',??,'07:00<=x<09:00'
'4',??,'09:00<=x<12:30'
'5',??,'09:00<=x<12:30'
```

How I can define weekday and weekend in data part!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, because your attribute definitions are a bit confusing. Shouldn't `is_Weekend` have values like `yes` and `no`? Because as it is now, each data point needs a weekend day and a weekday.

Assuming they are how you want them, you could set the attribute which does not fit to missing:

```
@data
'1',?,'Monday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'2',?,'Thursday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'3','Saturday',?,'07:00<=x<09:00'
'4',?,'Monday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'5','Sunday',?,'09:00<=x<12:30'
```

I'd rather do it like this:

```
@relation
@attribute ID {'1','2','3','4','5'}
@attribute is_Weekend {yes, no}
@attribute Weekday {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday}
@attribute Leaving_Time {'07:00<=x<09:00','09:00<=x<12:30'}

@data
'1','no','Monday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'2','no','Thursday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'3','yes','Saturday','07:00<=x<09:00'
'4','no','Monday','09:00<=x<12:30'
'5','yes','Sunday','09:00<=x<12:30'
```